# Нужна помощь с mod_rewrite и динамическими поддоменами

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Доброго времени суток есть такая проблема: делаю динамические поддомены на apache с помощью mod_rewrite. Например user1.domain.ru должен попадать в domain.ru/user1 и так хоть сколько.
В .htaccess прописал

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.ru$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.ru/$1/ [L,P]
```

Все бы ничего, но выдает ошибку Not found. А если убрать флаг P, то просто идет перенаправление в нужную директорию. Как можно избавиться от перенаправления, чтобы ссылка оставалась user1.domain.ru

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Здесь мы указываем вебсерверу, что с поддомена www должен быть выполнен 301-й редирект на домен без www. Это полезно для унификации домена и ссылок на него с точки зрения поисковых систем.

Answer (score 0):

Делал как-то так:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(domain\.ru|localhost)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(domain\.ru|localhost)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/%1/$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(wordpress|mail|other)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /subdomain.php?%1/%2
```

Навскидку вспомнил. К обеду уточню точно, если есть ошибки.
Смысл такой: есть статичные домены, которые лежат в папках, а есть динамичные, которые обрабатываются скриптом subdomain.php.

Comment: Дело в том, что у разных динамичных поддоменов в своих папках разные скрипты.

Comment: Я привел Вам общий вид в котором можно создать статичные домены средствами сервера и проксировать запросы на все остальные динамичные домены, чтобы избежать внешнего редиректа. Если Вам это не нужно, то просто уберите два последних cond и последний Rule